# block copy file by certain size and extension using batch command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm new to batch command, and have a problem with blocking certain file size and extension when i'm try to copy by network.

for example : file with size > 5MB and extension *.mp3, will automaticly block if someone try to copy by network or locally.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what makes you think that _batch command_ can do that?

Comment: Are you just trying to stop your batch file from doing it, our are you trying to stop anybody from doing it? The batch file will only be able to stop itself

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expansion options to check for certain file extensions and sizes.

This command will only allow files < 5MB and without extension mp3

```
for %f in (*.*) do if /I %~zf LEQ 5000000 if /I "%~xf" NEQ ".mp3" copy %f \\srv\share\%f
```

#### How does this work?

Issuing `help if` on the command prompt reveals the options available:

> If Command Extensions are enabled IF changes as follows:
>   `IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command`
>   where compare-op may be one of:

```
EQU - equal
NEQ - not equal
LSS - less than
LEQ - less than or equal
GTR - greater than
GEQ - greater than or equal
```

> and the /I switch, if specified, says to do case insensitive string
>   compares.  The /I switch can also be used on the string1==string2 form
>   of IF.  These comparisons are generic, in that if both string1 and
>   string2 are both comprised of all numeric digits, then the strings are
>   converted to numbers and a numeric comparison is performed.

The for command allows iterating over each file in a directory:

> Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.
>   `FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]`

```
  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.
```

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.

And near the end of the for help page we find the substitution rules:

> In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
>   You can now use the following optional syntax:

```
...
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
....
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
```

Combining all this gives to above initial solution for filtering on file sources.